# Automatically executing Bean method on certain condition in jsp

Tags: jsp, jsf

I need to check for below condition,

```
if (request.getParameter("onumber") != null && request.getParameter("onumber") != "" && request.getParameter("ocode") != null && request.getParameter("ocode") != "") {
```

And if true, I need to call submit() method of StatusBean automatically.

I tried like below without testing onumber and ocode condition, but its not working. Am I missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {
alert("Called test"); //This is not even called
document.getElementById('LoginForm:submitButton1').click();
}

</script>

<body onload="test();">

<f:view>

<h:form id="LoginForm" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm();">
<h:commandButton style="display:none" action="#{StatusBean.submit}" id="submitButton1"/>
...
...
</h:form>

</f:view>

</body>
```

Also please let me know how to test with onumber and ocode condition.
Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense, but it has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the query parameters and store them in a backing bean and enable the button only when both of them are passed like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="onumber" value="#{userBean.onumber}"/>
    <f:viewParam name="ocode" value="#{userBean.ocode}"/>
  </f:metadata>
<h:head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form prependId="false">
      <h:commandButton  value="Submit" disabled="#{ empty userBean.onumber or empty userBean.ocode}" />
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

and create setters/getters for the parameters in your backing bean:

```
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String ocode;
private String onumber;
    public String getOcode() {
    return ocode;
}
public void setOcode(String ocode) {
    this.ocode = ocode;
}
public String getOnumber() {
    return onumber;
}
public void setOnumber(String onumber) {
    this.onumber = onumber;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the code above does not work, but this code does.  It's almost identical to yours.  Not sure why your's is not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
 <h:head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/local/tinstyle.css"/>
 </h:head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function doSubmit() {
  document.getElementById('mmTestForm:delBtn').click();
 }
 </script>
 <h:body onload="doSubmit()">
 <h:form id="mmTestForm" action="#{mmTestBean.delete}">
 <p:commandButton id="delBtn" value="" action="#{mmTestBean.delete}" ajax="false" />  
 </h:form>
 </h:body>
  </html>

package gov.irs.eservices.tin.mbeans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="mmTestBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MMTestBean {

 public String delete() {
      System.out.println("here");
      return "mainmenu";
    }
}
```